# EPPlus: How to set background color for Columns and Rows to be different, expand the width and set the single cell as a name of the spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, epplus

I'm using EPPlus library to map `DataTable` to excel. This is my code:

```
using (pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
        ws.Cells["A1:I1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:I1"])
        {
            rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;

            rng.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            rng.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            rng.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);

            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood);

            ws.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            ws.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Bisque);

            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;

            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);

        }
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + ReportName + ".xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

When running the above code, I have the following result:

[image]

I need to have something like that:

[image]

As you see, background colors for columns and rows are different, width of columns is bigger and the report has a name.

How can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order. First set for whole WorkSheet, then for the Range. At the moment you override the Range color by setting the WorkSheet color.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution:

```
using (pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
            ws.Cells["A5:I5"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
            ws.DefaultColWidth = 25;

            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;

            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            ws.Cells.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            var headerCell = ws.Cells["A5:I5"];
            headerCell.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            headerCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood);
            var headerFont = headerCell.Style.Font;
            headerFont.Bold = true;
            int totalRow = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
            int totalCol = ws.Dimension.End.Column;
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[6,1,totalRow,totalCol])
            {

                rng.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
                rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
                rng.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
                rng.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;

                rng.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                rng.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                rng.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                rng.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);

                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Bisque);

            }
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            ws.Cells["A4"].LoadFromText(name + " Generation Time: " + elapsedMs.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + name + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());

}
```

I just had to swap the setting of Worksheet with the Range